# Fontawesome 5 extra top and bottom padding

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Is there any way to remove the extra top and bottom padding for Fontawesome 5 icon as shown in the image (after adding a red background color)

[image]

`<i class="fab fa-5x fa-facebook" style="background-color: red;"></i>`

Simple fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/68d05etb/15/

Answer (score 2):

To eliminate extra padding in text/icons you can set a static `line-height` for the icon.

i.e. if you font-awesome icon is `30px` tall but `5px` of that is padding then you can do the following:

`i{line-height: 25px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is right way to do it, but changing the `line-height` doesn't work for me. I end up creating the same effect I want by using `fa-layers`

`<a href="#" class="fa-layers fa-fw" target="_blank">
    <i class="fas fa-square" style="color: #FFFFFF;"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook" style="color: #3C5995;"></i>
</a>`